# How to implement a custom ViewProcessor<T> (jax-rs)?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey, el, jax-rs

Looking at the article [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/sandoz/entry/mvcj), there is an example of how to use a TemplateProcessor to resolve JSP views using Jersey.  Apparently this class has been deprecated now and replaced by ViewProcessor<T>. I am somewhat confused about how to implement either (preferably the newer one since it isn't deprecated); what goes in as the template argument? How can I implement one to simply resolve jsps in /WebContent/WEB-INF/views/* and also evaluate the expression language of the returned view?

The other [ViewProcessor article is here.](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Deprecated-TemplateProcessor-Use-ViewProcessor-td4231771.html)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ViewProcessor should be implemented if you want to plug in support for a new type of templates. If all you need is JSP templates, then that's already built into Jersey and you don't need to implement your own ViewProcessor.

If your JSP files are located under WEB-INF/views, then you can set the [JSP_TEMPLATES_BASE_PATH](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/servlet/ServletContainer.html#JSP_TEMPLATES_BASE_PATH) init parameter to WEB-INF/views. Then you just need to return a new instance of Viewable from your resource method (as illustrated by Paul's blog you are referring to) and pass the template name as the first parameter and data (model) as the second parameter to the constructor. Then in the JSP you can access the data using the attribute named "it".

UPDATE: If your url-pattern is "/*" it is a bit more complicated. Jersey is not able to resolve the templates when delegating to the container, as the Jersey servlet is masking out the JSPs. To make it possible for the container to see the JSPs, you need to do two more things:

1. register the Jersey servlet as a filter instead of a servlet (simply replace occurrences of servlet by filter in your web.xml) - see the bottom of this javadoc page: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/servlet/package-summary.html
2. add [PROPERTY_WEB_PAGE_CONTENT_REGEX](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/servlet/ServletContainer.html#PROPERTY_WEB_PAGE_CONTENT_REGEX) init param to the filter and set it to the regular expression that the jsp templates match (e.g. "/WEB-INF/views/.*")

If you still believe you have to implement a custom ViewProcessor for some reason, you can look at how the freemarker view processor is implemented and get inspired by that - see http://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/content/trunk/jersey/contribs/jersey-freemarker/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/freemarker/FreemarkerViewProcessor.java?rev=5453

Comment: I tried adding the init param and a call to return a viewable, but the view still can't be resolved:
    `<init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.JSPTemplatesBasePath</param-name>
      <param-value>WEB-INF/views</param-value>
    </init-param>`

and

    `return new Viewable("welcome",changeList);`

and a welcome.jsp file at WEB-INF/views/welcome.jsp

Comment: OK. This is because, as the article states, Jersey is looking for the templates in the following directory: <root>/<fullyQualifiedClassName>/. I.e., if the resource class returning Viewable is com.acme.myproject.FooResource and you are looking for "welcome", then Jersey will be trying to locate it as WEB-INF/views/com/acme/myproject/FooResource/welcome.jsp. If your template is in the root of the templates base path, you need to prefix the template name with a slash - i.e. `return new Viewable("/welcome", changeList);`

Comment: That makes sense, unfortunately that is not working for me either - I'm not getting an unresolved exception, but I'm not seeing the view either (HTTP 404). Does it matter that my servlet url-pattern is /*? Do you have any additional ideas? I'm really stumped / frustrated.

Comment: One thing I noticed while debugging is that the viewable's resolvingClass is null - that sounds incorrect, right?

Comment: OK, the problem is the url pattern. I've updated my answer with info on what to do if your url pattern is "/*".

Comment: Thank you soo much! I really appreciate it, everything's working now. One last question, how do you change the base url of your application? I've tried setting display name and changing the actual project name, but it always uses the old project name.

Comment: Depends on which container you are using. You need to set the context root to the desired value. For GlassFish this is done in glassfish-web.xml by adding the following element under the root: `<context-root>/desired-app-path</context-root>`

Comment: I'm using tomcat, i'll try that in the web.xml file