# Why Jersey "default" JSP processor is null under embedded Grizzly?

Tags: jsp, rest, jersey, grizzly

Using Grizzly 2.3.2 and Jersey 1.8 , according to many resources ([How to implement a custom ViewProcessor<T> (jax-rs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931469/how-to-implement-a-custom-viewprocessort-jax-rs), [blog](http://www.lucubratory.eu/simple-jerseyrest-and-jsp-based-web-application/)) Jersey comes w/ off the shelf JSP processor, yet debug sessions shows that no such processor exist

```
/**
     * Get the set of template processors.
     *
     * @return the set of template processors.
*/
private Set<ViewProcessor> getViewProcessors() {
     return viewProcessors; // ***THIS LIST IS EMPTY !!!***
}
```

I'd be grateful if someone could solve it/provide advice how to plug some JSP processor (not general purpose template engine !) into Jersey

Answer (score 3):

I've created a [sample maven project](https://github.com/oleksiys/samples/tree/master/grizzly-jersey-jsp-sample) (based on [this](http://www.lucubratory.eu/simple-jerseyrest-and-jsp-based-web-application/) webapp). It uses Jersey's JSP Viewable and runs on standalone Grizzly server.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Grizzly doesn't support JSP.  That's most likely the reason.